# 2D Array Search from Python to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

Whats is the equivalent of this code in Javascript?

```
array = ["James", "1", "3"]
array2 = ["Bob", "2", "5"]

mainArray = [array, array2]

Person = "James"

for element in mainArray:
    if (element[0] == Person):
        print Person + " " + "D=" + element[1] + " Z=" + element[2]
```

I have managed to create the arrays in Javascript but I am unsure how to code the for loop in a JS function.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 0; i < mainArray.length; i++){
    if(mainArray[i][0] == Person){
        console.log(mainArray[i][1] + " " + mainArray[i][2]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var arr1 = ["James", "1", "3"],
    arr2 = ["Bob", "2", "5"]
    arrMain = [];
arrMain.push(arr1 , arr2);

for(x=0; x<arrMain.length; x+=1){
   (arrMain[x][0] === 'James') && 
   console.log(arrMain[x][0] + " " + "D=" + arrMain[x][1] + " Z=" + arrMain[x][2])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = ["James", "1", "3"]
array2 = ["Bob", "2", "5"]
mainArray = array.concat(array2)
len = mainArray.length
for(var i=0;i<len;++i){
 if (mainArray[i] == "James"){
  console.log(mainArray[i]);
 }
}
```

Comment: Please review your answer. The solution you provided does not yield the same result as the original python code.